# undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in azure storage c++ sdk compilation

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I am trying to compile Azure storage c++ SDK on Fedora 22. I am using gcc version 5.1.1-1. When I compile test application using following command:

```
$> CASABLANCA_DIR=/source/codebox/azure/cpprestsdk/ CXX=g++ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTS=on

$> make
```

It produces following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/azurestoragetest.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tests/CMakeFiles/azurestoragetest.dir/build.make:879: recipe for target 'Binaries/azurestoragetest' failed
make[2]: *** [Binaries/azurestoragetest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:125: recipe for target 'tests/CMakeFiles/azurestoragetest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/azurestoragetest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can see *libpthread.so.0* library in */usr/lib64* directory. Which other library I need to install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the right `find_package` invokation to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Threads)
```

Then, link the library to your target:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

That's all. Likely you forgot the `target_link_libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

In general (outside of CMake and Azure Storage SDK), this error indicates you need to link with `-lpthread`. (With gcc you likely want `-pthread`.)